# Change the countdown speed based on user input

Tags: php, html, timer, countdown

Let's say default timer right now is 1sec decreasing every second (default), and the problem is that how do I change the countdown speed based on user input (user input 3, (system countdown decrease 3 every second)

https://jsfiddle.net/9q8wLyhs/ , this is the example code

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yantramanav:400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo" style="background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#b8b0af 0%,#f2ecea 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#b8b0af 0%,#f2ecea 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#b8b0af 0%,#f2ecea 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#b8b0af 0%,#f2ecea 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top,#b8b0af 0%,#f2ecea 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
position:relative;font-size:1.2em;font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;font-weight:900;text-align: center;

"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("May 5, 2019 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

(user input 3, (system countdown decrease 3 every second)

Comment: where does the `user` input anything??

Comment: This looks like `javascript`, not `PHP`. Please use the correct language tags

Comment: sorry, did not include my others code , i will closing this question and post a new one with updated codes